# How do I use a new local module?

Tags: module, rust, rust-cargo

I'm unable to import and use a module I've written, not sure where I went wrong.

My starting directory structure is:

```
/src/main.rs <- contains fn main()
/Cargo.toml
```

I wanted to refactor some code out of one big main file I had, so I ran

```
cargo new mnemonic
```

leaving me with:

```
/src/main.rs <- contains fn main()
/Cargo.toml
/mnemonic/src/lib.rs
/mnemonic/Cargo.toml
```

in the `/mnemonic/src/lib.rs` that was created I put:

```
pub mod mnemonic;
```

then put my code in `/mnemonic/src/mnemonic.rs` (has 2 public functions I want to use from `main`). I ran `cargo build` from `mnemonic/` and back in my main src, I tried

```
extern crate mnemonic;
```

and

```
use mnemonic;
```

I also tried `use mnemonic::mnemonic`;

In all instances, it was unable to find the crate or gave an unresolved import error.

I've also tried putting my code containing the 2 pub functions in `/src/mnemonic.rs`

and in `/src/main.rs` putting:

```
use mnemonic;
```

I also tried just putting my code in `mnemonic/src/lib.rs` and trying `extern crate mnemonic; use mnemonic;` from `src/main.rs`

Am I supposed to edit `Cargo.toml` in any of the instances you proposed?

Comment: You may want to brush up on the terminology here. I know it's confusing when you first start with it, but there's an important difference between a *crate* and a *module*. You created a new crate when you ran `cargo new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Yes, you need to tell Cargo where to find your crate. In your binaries `Cargo.toml`, add something like:

```
[dependencies.mnemonic]
path = "./mnemonic"
```

### Original Answer

When you create a new crate, it automatically has one layer of namespacing: the name of the crate itself. In addition, you don't need to `extern use` a crate if it is your current crate!

#### Using crate `mnemonic` from other crates

This is probably what you want to do: Create a new crate called `mnemonic`, then you will have a `src/lib.rs`. Put your code in there, and you can then use it from *other crates* with

```
extern crate mnemonic;
use mnemonic::ItemInLibDotRs; // Make sure this item is marked as `pub`!
```

#### Using a nested module `mnemonic` from the crate `mnemonic`

Say you have some implementation detail you want to hide from the end user. We will put it in a module within the crate, and use it *only from within the same crate*.

Put your code in `src/mnemonic.rs`. In `src/lib.rs`, you will reference that module and items:

```
use mnemonic::ItemInMnemonic; // Make sure this is `pub`!
mod mnemonic;
```

#### Using a nested module `mnemonic` from the crate `mnemonic` in other crates

Export the module from your crate, and then reference it from *other crates*:

```
// src/lib.rs
pub mod mnemonic; // Note the module is now public

// In the crate that consumes mnemonic
extern crate mnemonic;
use mnemonic::mnemonic::ItemInMnemonic;
```

This last option is kind of ugly though, you probably don't want to make your users type `mnemonic::mnemonic`, which is why I suggest just putting it in `src/lib.rs`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, put my code mnemonic/src/lib.rs. ran cargo build in the mnemonic dir. then in src/main.rs i put extern crate mnemonic; use mnemonic;. I get the error 'can't find crate for mnemonic'

Comment: @leshow I think we got crossed (your question is a bit ambiguous). I've reformatted my answer to show you the 3 possibilities better. I think you are combining #1 and #2, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think we are still not fully understanding each other, I tried the suggestions and wasn't able to get it working, I edited my original post to better show the project directory structure.